# recv crash without return

Tags: tcp, crash, recv

I have this piece of code, where I should receive some data over a TCP socket:

```
int ret;
char mytext[SIZE_CTRL_MSG];
cerr << "Trying to receive" << endl;
ret = recv(sock, &mytext[0], SIZE_CTRL_MSG, 0);
cerr << "Packet received, ret=" << ret << endl;
if(ret == SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf("recv failed with error (%d)\n", WSAGetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(1);
}
```

but when I try to execute it, the application crashes without returning a value; the output is this:

```
Trying to receive
```

and here the application crashes. I only receive a message, "Unhandled exception win32 occurred". I'm using eclipse Juno on Windows XP. I tried changing `&mytext[0]` with `mytext` in the recv(), but I have the same situation. Which can be the error?

Comment: Are you sure that `sock` is valid ? (i.e. was previous call to `sock = socket(...);` successful ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Before the receive, i use `sock` for a send(), and it works.